# VBA ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveAsName custom name (SaveAsName) not appearing in dialog

Tags: vba, excel

I'm hoping somebody can help me with this.  I'm creating a model in Excel using VBA and want to populate the Save As dialog with a custom filename.  I have three pieces of code.  The first is for a userform that asks the end-user to enter the name of their facility:

```
Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
strHospName = frmHospName.txtHospName.Value

'   Check for a usable hospital name

If Len(strHospName) = 0 Then
    frmHospName.Hide
    MsgBox "Please provide the name of your facility.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Missing Facility Name"
    frmHospName.Show
End If

If (Len(strHospName) - Len(Trim(strHospName)) = Len(strHospName)) Then
    frmHospName.Hide
    MsgBox "Please provide the name of your facility.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Missing Facility Name"
    frmHospName.Show
End If

If strHospName Like "*[\/:*?""<>|]*" Then
    frmHospName.Hide
    MsgBox "Please enter your facility's name without any of the following characters:   \ / : * ? < > | ", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Invalid Facility Name"
    frmHospName.Show
End If

Call SaveAsNameStore(strHospName, MyName)

Set currForm = Me
Unload Me
End Sub
```

The second piece lives in its own module and checks to see if this model has already been customized (a customized model will not see frmHospName upon workbook open, thus strHospName will not get assigned), and based on that check, it creates the string SaveAsName:

```
Public strHospName As String
Public SaveAsName As String

Function MyName() As String
    MyName = ThisWorkbook.Name
End Function

Sub SaveAsNameStore(strHospName As String, MyName As String)
'    This code creates a custom SaveAs name
    Dim strModelDate As String
    strModelDate = Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")
    If (Len(strHospName) - Len(Trim(strHospName)) = Len(strHospName)) Then
        SaveAsName = MyName
    Else
        SaveAsName = strHospName & " customized economic model " & strModelDate
    End If
End Sub
```

The third piece lives in ThisWorkbook and applies SaveAsName in Workbook_BeforeSave:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

''This code forces SaveAs with custom filename instead of Save to prevent overwriting the master model file
''NEED TO UNCOMMENT PRIOR TO DELIVERY

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If SaveAsUI = False Then
        Cancel = True
    ElseIf SaveAsUI = True Then
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If .Show Then
                ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename = SaveAsName
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that, when I click the "Save As" button, the custom SaveAs name isn't populating in the dialog.  I can see that SaveAsName is generated correctly via `?SaveAsName` in the Immediate window.  For syntax, I've tried both `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename = SaveAsName` and `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveAsName` with the same result both times.

Sorry for the long-winded post.  I would appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: Why not simply implement `BeforeSave` with `Cancel = True`, and have your custom "save as" disable application events and actually perform the `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs` call? Seems you're over-complicating things, unless I'm misunderstanding something... right now it seems your `SaveAsNameStore` procedure's name is lying - it's not *saving* anything really.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for your reply.  `SaveAsNameStore` is storing the custom Save As name - I suppose I should've called it `StoreSaveAsName` to be more clear.

I'm not sure I understand the rest of your comment - could you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Still, I would avoid the event-handler spaghetti and programmatically save the workbook - if I understand correctly the file name to use is known already, not sure why a SaveAs dialog needs to pop up only for the user to okay it.

Comment: I guess for user experience - so the end-user knows the model has been saved.  But I can handle that with a MsgBox.  Thank you - I don't know why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

This is something I use to make a backup of something I'm currently working in, without naming it the same thing. Easily modified for your situation and variables

```
Private Sub cmdBackupButton_Click()
'__BACKUP THE CURRENT WORKBOOK___

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\WhateverPathYouWant\myFile_backup.xlsb")
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

This eliminates any "save as" dialogue, and needs no interaction. Very simple.

Comment: Thanks very much for this!